# Why is my Javascript logging Unlogged values to the CodeCademy Console?

Tags: javascript, console.log

This has happened many times and I've just ignored it until now, however it's bugging me because I'm not sure if my code will be correct.

The issue is that when I console.log(TextA) or (TextB) and then put a value into a variable, the console will log the value that I push to the variable.

Example below:

My CodeCademy code is:

```
var slaying = true;
var youHit = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 1);
var damageThisRound = Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 1);
var totalDamage = 0;

while (slaying) {
    if (youHit) {
        console.log("Congrats, you hit");
    } else {
        console.log("You were defeated by the dragon");
    } 
    slaying = false;
}
```

And my console log is:

```
Congrats, you hit
false
```

Does this happen to anyone else? is it just an error with the CodeCademy system or is my Javascript not correct?

Comment: Also, it doesn't seem to work the same way if I put the slaying = false before the console.log, as in:

    while (slaying) {
        slaying = false;
        if (youHit) {
            console.log("Congrats, you hit");
        } else {
            console.log("You were defeated by the dragon");
        } 
    }

Is this something that I should be aware of moving forward about Javascript as a language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because their interpreter, much like the browser console, evaluates all of the code you put into it and all operations in javascript have a return value. Try this for example:

```
var y = (foo = 'x');
console.log(y);
```

The assignment operation has a return value. This becomes more apparent when you use things like `eval` and `new Function` to evaluate code, because they will show you the value of the last interpreted line of code, then you see that even `do..while` statements have a return value. If you change the last line of your `while` statement, you will see that the last value is logged instead of `false`.

Here is another example using `eval` that might demonstrate better:

```
eval('var foo = 0; i = 0; while( i < 2 ) { i++; foo = i * 9; } ')
```

Note that I didn't log anything explicitly there, but because `foo = i * 9` (where `i = 2`) was the last line evaluated, you will see `18` in your console. Also note that if I had included `var` in that statement, you would see `1` instead, because `i++` would be the last operation that returned a value (to add to the confusion, `var` assignments return `undefined`).

Comment: I didn't quite understand the example you gave. On one hand, I would expect that foo = 'x' and so y = (foo) would make y = 'x', but foo isn't a var, so why is it accepting it as an input parameter?

Comment: But otherwise I understand what you mean, are you telling me that this is just an issue with browser console, and that it won't affect alerts or actual functions that I write to do things that aren't console-related?

Comment: You are correct, it will not have any direct side effects, it's mostly console related, though in many ways it can be used to your advantage. I'm adding another example with eval that you can run that will hopefully show what I mean.